# In python, how do I make a class instance be implicit?

Tags: python

I'm creating a module with turtle integrated into Tkinter, and I would to be able to use turtle functions such as `forward(10)` without having to write `moduleTurtle.forward(10)`. Here is my current code:

```
#myModule
import Tkinter as tk
import turtle as tr

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
moduleTurtle = tr.RawTurtle(canvas)
```

And here is what a user would have to write to use turtle:

```
#userModule
from myModule import *
moduleTurtle.forward(10)
```

How can I make moduleTurtle "implicit", as in not have to type it to call turtle functions? I would like to avoid rewriting every single turtle function. Also, importing turtle inside userModule creates an extra window, which I don't want either.

For context, I will be giving myModule to python beginners, so I want it to be as simple to use as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in myModule, just affect moduleTurtle method to a variable and in the user module, just call the variables after doing 'from myModule import *'

```
#myModule 
import Tkinter as tk
import turtle as tr

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
moduleTurtle = tr.RawTurtle(canvas)
forward = moduleTurtle.forward #method "forward" of moduleTurtle affected to forward



#userModule
from myModule import *
forward(10)
```

for a general usage use this in myModule

```
#myModule 
import Tkinter as tk
import turtle as tr
import sys


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
moduleTurtle = tr.RawTurtle(canvas)
current_module = sys.modules[__name__]
d = current_module.__dict__
for el in moduleTurtle.__dict__:
    if not el.startswith('_'):
        obj = getattr(moduleTurtle, el)
        if hasattr(obj, '__call__'):
            d[el] = obj
```

Comment: I think the OP gave forward as an example but instead wants to expose all the turtle methods to the user through his own module.

Comment: I'm having trouble making this work... My dummy userModule is telling me forward isnt defined. I never learned to use sys, but that 'el' in d['el'] = obj sounds wrong.
I should mention that I want to attach turtle to Tkinter from a function, but that only needs a few more global keywords to work properly.

Comment: ChaoTech see change it is d[el]=obj

Comment: Okay, I've got it working, mostly. Turns out most of turtle's functions such as forward are defined by the module, not the RawTurtle instance. Here are the changes I've made to make it work: `for el in tr.__dict__.keys()` and `obj = getattr(tr, el)`.

This code will work if it is used in the main body of myModule. Since it will be in a function, the extra change I'm trying to implement is giving userModule to `current_module = sys.modules[__name__]` instead of `__name__`. (putting it in a function prevents the functions from entering userModule.__dict__ during the import phase)

Comment: ChaoTech it is the same thing but more robust. for el in tr.__dict__  is the same as for el in tr.__dict__.keys()  don't know what is the difference? yes in fact I did it to use it in myModule...see the title for this part.